# Generic Function pointer to the class member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

How can I have generic function pointer. Consider following class.

```
#ifndef PERSON_HPP_
#define PERSON_HPP_

#include <string>

class Person {
public:
  Person() {
  }
  void SetName(std::string person_name) {
    m_name = person_name;
  }
  void setDept(std::string dept_name) {
    m_dept = dept_name;
  }
  void setAge(int person_age ) {
    m_age = person_age;
  }
  std::string getName() {
    return m_name;
  }
  std::string getDept() {
    return m_dept;
  }
  int getAge() {
    return m_age;
  }
private:
  std::string m_name;
  std::string m_dept;
  int m_age;
};

#endif
```

I want to store the function pointers in a `std::vector` for `setName`, `setDept` , `constructor` and so on `...`

For normal function I could achieve this using following

```
#include <vector>


int mult(int a) { 
  return 2*a; 
}

int main()
{
    int b;

    std::vector<void *(*)(void *)> v;
    v.push_back((void *(*)(void *))mult);
    b = ((int (*)(int)) v[0])(2);        // The value of b is 2.

    return 0;
}
```

No `Boost` allowed in my case.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, chances are it's a bad idea, architecture-wise...

Comment: Using function pointer in this case is an overkill.

Comment: @iammilind what is the other option

Comment: Last time i checked, a function pointer could only have one signature (i.e. parameters). It doesn't seem to be the case here. How can your constructor, setName and setDept could have the same signature?

Comment: @Avinash: The other option is avoiding the need for this construct altogether, using either OO or generic programming (templates) to solve the underlying problem. Since you didn't tell us the underlying problem you are trying to solve with function pointers, we cannot tell you the underlying solution. (That's why you should always attempt to ask about solutions to the underlying problem, not about problems with a specific solution you came up with. ;-) )

Comment: @DevSolar: Thanks, I have API in which user will give me class name and memebers name and its Setter and Getter, I want to store it in some datastructure so that I can call it on the object if the name is same

Comment: @Avinash: *gulp*... OK... I wouldn't touch an API like that with a ten-foot pole. Good luck - but consider using a saner API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* need to cast the member pointers to a common type (like void*), you can do:

```
template <typename T>
void* castToVoidStar(T x) {
  return *reinterpret_cast<void**>(&x);
}

void *afterCast = castToVoidStar(&Person::getName)
```

However, I do not believe it is wise to do so. C++ has type safety for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
// Pointer to member function as a data type. 
typedef void (Person::*MethodPtr)(std::string); 
std::vector<MethodPtr> v;
```

Pointers to members are not any way different from any other data types. Only it should be used as binary operator:

```
Person *bad_guy = ...;
bad_guy->*v[4]("abcd");
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to avoid the re-writing the `getter/setter` method, which typically have similar code inside.
However, it's a bad idea to use function pointer for such task because it reduces readability, adds complexity and doesn't allow the compiler to do the optimizations related to **inlining**.

If you want to automate the code generation for using `getter/setter` then use editor which has facility to generate getter/setter such as eclipse or you can resort to macros in this case:

```
#define SETTER(TYPE,FIELD) \
  set##FIELD (const TYPE FIELD) \
  { \
    this->m_##FIELD = FIELD; \
  }
#define GETTER(FIELD) \
  get##FIELD () const \
  { \
    return this->m_##FIELD; \
  }
```

And use it as,

```
class Person {
public:
  Person() {
  }
  void SETTER(std::string, name);
  void SETTER(std::string, dept);
  void SETTER(int, age);

  int GETTER(name);
  int GETTER(dept);
  int GETTER(age);

private:
  std::string m_name;
  std::string m_dept;
  int m_age;
};

#undef SETTER
#undef GETTER
```

Comment: @iammilind: Thanks, I thought about similar approach, but unfortunately I cannot touch user classes. This is my main problem.

Comment: @Als, do you mean the type safety is compromised in macro solution? Can you elaborate what part.

Comment: Getters and setters are a "code smell", as they are usually a sign that the RAII concept is broken. If you have lots of getters and setters, consider if your class should perhaps be a struct instead.

Comment: @DevSolar, the getter/setter is not my idea by the way :), it's in question. I doubt if it's a code smell. Most of the Java code has such getters/setters. It depends on the class or API whether to have it or not.

Comment: @iammilind: Yes, Java code has lots of this - because Java doesn't have structs. That's why I shudder when people take Java concepts and transpose them to C++. The two are fundamentally different in many ways.